# Setting relative path in Geckodriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@".\","geckodriver.exe");
```

That was my code.
I have my `geckodriver.exe` at the root folder, where my test DLL file is available. *(inside bin\Debug)*

The above code is not working because it can't find the `geckodriver.exe`.
So how am I giving the relative path to `geckodriver.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should find `geckodriver.exe` then copy its path as below

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, then right-click the document.

In the context menu that appears, find and click Copy as path. This copies the file location to the clipboard

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste in the file location to code below you should change "/" to  "\"

```
@Before

  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\recepc\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.tr/";

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

Comment: In your code still you are using the absolute path.

Comment: And im up to c# on visual studio

Answer (score 1):

I found a way,
1st i have to check what was the currant location which my test is going to execute.
Actually i was thinking that is inside the bin folder but i was wrong.

```
 string value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

From this you can get the actual location where your test project is building right now.

in my case it is on `E:\\Users\\<user>\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\TestWithSelenium3\\TestResults\\cja_ES-NB-110 2017-01-18 22_43_22\\Out`

Then based on the above location i have to give the relative path.
My Gecko driver was inside the `TestWithSelenium3` folder so i have to move back 3 time as below.

```
@"..\..\..\TestWithSelenium3"
```

Then it works,

SO the final code looks like

```
string value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                //E:\\Users\\<user>\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\TestWithSelenium3\\TestResults\\cja_ES-NB-110 2017-01-18 22_43_22\\Out"
    FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"..\..\..\TestWithSelenium3", "geckodriver.exe");
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: If this works, resolves your question, then I'd suggest marking this as your answer!